# Getting the Href from a collection of links

Tags: javascript

Using basic javascript I can find all of the a_hrefs I am interested in. How do I convert this list of objects into just a list of URL strings?

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='https://aaaa/']")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.from`, which takes an array-like object, and whose second parameter is an (optional) mapper function:

```
const urls = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='https://aaaa/']"),
  a => a.href
);
```

Comment: I always forgot about the optional mapping function